# C Guessing game Upper and Lower Bound

Tags: c

Ok so this program asks the user to input a lower and upper bound and the object is for the program to guess the number based off a feedback system (-1,0,1). Everything works and compiles its just every time i give it feedback it doubles up a number see output for example. Any help would greatly be appreciated, since im still learning always open to suggestions thanks

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {

int low;
int high;
int Guess;
int feedback;


printf("Enter Upper bound number: ");
scanf("%d", &high);

printf("Enter lower bound number: ");
scanf("%d", &low);

Guess = (high - low)/2+low;


while (feedback != 0) 
{

printf("my guess is: %d ", Guess);

printf("What do you think?");
scanf("%d", &feedback);

//guess was too low 
if (feedback == -1)
{
Guess = Guess+1; 
printf("my guess is: %d ", Guess);

printf("What do you think?");
scanf("%d", &feedback);
}

//guess was too high
else if (feedback == 1)
{
Guess = Guess-1; 
printf("my guess is: %d ", Guess);

printf("What do you think?");
scanf("%d", &feedback);
}

 else if (feedback == 0)
{
printf("I win!\n");
}
}

return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Enter a upper bound number: 40
Enter a lower bound number: 20
my guess is: 30 what do you think? -1
my guess is: 31 what do you think? -1
my guess is: 31 what do you think? -1
my guess is: 32 what do you think? -1
my guess is: 32 what do you think? -1
my guess is: 33 what do you think? -1
my guess is: 33 what do you think? -1
my guess is: 34 what do you think? -1
my guess is: 34 what do you think? -1
my guess is: 35 what do you think? 0
I win!
```

Answer (score 1):

Suggested changes to bisect the remaining range after each guesss.

```
// Initialize
int feedback = !0;  // @Digital_Reality

// Guess = (high - low)/2+low;
Guess = (high + low)/2;

//guess was too low 
if (feedback == -1) {
  // Guess = Guess+1; 
  low = Guess+1;
  Guess = (high + low)/2;
  ....

//guess was too high
else if (feedback == 1) {
  // Guess = Guess-1; 
  high = Guess-1;
  Guess = (high + low)/2;
  ....
```

Comment: you are fast!.. about to write comment on feedback = 0 :)

Answer (score 1):

Take your `printfs` before `while loop.` Anyway you have those inside `if`

```
printf("my guess is: %d ", Guess);
printf("What do you think?");
scanf("%d", &feedback);
while (feedback != 0) 
{
    //guess was too low 
    if (feedback == -1)
    {
```

PS: Initialize `feedback` with `1` or other +ve number.

Answer (score 0):

Chux is correct. If you don't want your program to repeat itself then you simply take out the printf and scanf in the if statements or bring the print/scanf inside the while loop to the outside.

Answer (score 0):

You're getting double output because of your loop. You're testing the input, then in your 'if' you're printing your guess and accepting input again. Once input is received, the loop restarts and prints the current value of guess And requests input. In your 'if', simply change the value of guess and let the loop continue rather than prompting.